# When ever i am trying to run mongo command i get this below error

Tags: mongodb

"couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check that you have create the database folder in the right location, C:\data\db , then go to your bin folder where you have installed mongodb and type cmd in the address bar, and type mongod command which will start the mongodb server. Then open anothe terminal type cmd in the address bar in the same location and type mongod.